# How to substitute a entire line for a specific value Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a 4x4 matrix B. I want to substitue the entire first line for a specific value (2):

```
B[0]=2.0
```

If I put this way the first line becomes `[2,[....],[....],[....]]` and not `[[2,2,2,2],[....],[....],[....]]`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `B[0] = [2 for x in range(4)]`

you could also do `B[0] = [2,2,2,2]` but if the size changes then you can put
`B[0] = [2 for x in range(size)]`